# How to create a shared library to be used with <uses-library> element

Tags: android, shared-libraries

Is there any example of creating **shared library** referenced [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#libs)

> However, some packages reside in their
>   own libraries. If your application
>   uses code from any of these packages,
>   it must explicitly asked to be linked
>   against them. The manifest must
>   contain a separate 
>   element to name each of the libraries.
>   (The library name can be found in the
>   documentation for the package.)

And [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html)

> Specifies a shared library that the
>   application must be linked against.
>   This element tells the system to
>   include the library's code in the
>   class loader for the package.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html this is the only thing I know of that uses it.

Comment: They show only how to use the shared library, not how to create.